# why is mysql allowing to delete records referenced by a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

My question is why i am able to delete records from dept table, which have corresponding records present in emp table.

For example , i am able to delete record in dept table where deptno = 10, while a record in emp table is referencing that using the foreign key.

```
mysql> select * from emp;
+-------+-------+---------+------+----------+------+------+--------+
| empno | ename | job     | mgr  | hiredate | sal  | comm | deptno |
+-------+-------+---------+------+----------+------+------+--------+
|  7698 | BLAKE | MANAGER | 7839 | NULL     | 2850 | NULL |     30 |
|  7782 | CLARK | MANAGER | 7839 | NULL     | 2450 | NULL |     10 |
+-------+-------+---------+------+----------+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from dept;
+--------+------------+----------+
| deptno | dname      | loc      |
+--------+------------+----------+
|     10 | ACCOUNTING | NEW YORK |
|     20 | RESEARCH   | DALLAS   |
|     30 | SALES      | CHICAGO  |
|     40 | OPERATIONS | BOSTON   |
+--------+------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> delete from dept where deptno = 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE dept( deptno int, dname varchar(14), loc varchar(13), PRIMARY KEY (deptno));

CREATE TABLE emp( empno int, ename varchar(10), job varchar(9), mgr int, hiredate date, sal int, comm int, deptno int, PRIMARY KEY (empno),FOREIGN KEY (deptno) REFERENCES dept (deptno));

INSERT INTO dept VALUES(10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO dept VALUES(20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO dept VALUES(30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO dept VALUES(40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');


INSERT INTO emp
VALUES( 7698,
        'BLAKE',
        'MANAGER',
        7839,
        STR_TO_DATE('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
        2850,
        NULL,
        30);


INSERT INTO emp
VALUES( 7782,
        'CLARK',
        'MANAGER',
        7839,
        STR_TO_DATE('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),
        2450,
        NULL,
        10);
```

Thanks in advance .

This is my show table structure for emp

```
mysql> show create table dept;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------
| Table | Create Table
+-------+---------------------------------------------------
| dept  | CREATE TABLE `dept` (
  `deptno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dname` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deptno`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. I am unable to understand your question..

Comment: are you using InnoDB engine? myISAM does not enforce foreign keys constraints

Comment: if i am able to delete records present in deptno , the corresponding records im emp table  will have no value know .

Comment: @guido , i have added my show table emp command result in my question .

Comment: yes you are using MyISAM engine; you need INNODB enabled in the server and set it as the default engine, or create the tables using the INNODB engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MyISAM` storage engine will accept foreign keys declarations, but will not enforce the constraints; to be able to guarantee foreign key integrity, you can switch to the `InnoDB` engine, globally specifying this in mysql configuration file `my.cnf`:

```
 [mysqld]
 ...
 default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

or locally in the database, dropping the tables, then re-adding them with the complete mysql specific syntax like:

```
 CREATE TABLE `dept` (
  `deptno` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dname` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deptno`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

note: InnoDB is default storage engine since Mysql 5.5, to determine if InnoDB is available in your setup, execute the query: `SHOW ENGINES`

Answer (score 2):

The MyISAM storage engine that you're using does not enforce foreign key constraints. If you want them enforced you should use another storage engine, such as InnoDB.

To quote the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (**such as MyISAM**), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.